# How can I overlay a number on top of a FontAwesome glyph?

Tags: css, font-awesome

How can I overlay a number between 0 and 99 in the middle of 'icon-star-empty'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You css should look something like:

```
.contain-i-e-s,.icon-empty-star,.text-i-e-s{
  height:100px; width:100px;
}
.contain-i-e-s{
  position:relative;
}
.text-i-e-s{
  text-align:center; position:absolute;
}
```

Your HTML might look like:

```
<div class='contain-i-e-s'>
  <i class='icon-empty-star'></i>
  <div class='text-i-e-s'>99</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure why this was the accepted answer. I just gave a CSS answer, not fully understanding Font Awesome at the time. I actually voted the other guy up.

Answer (score 123):

Simply do this from the [Font Awesome docs on Stacked Icons](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/examples/#stacked):

```html
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
    <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-stack-1x">1</i>
</span>
```

[image: Font Awesome Docs Screenshot]

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/tagliala/SNVRp/ for an example that works for font-awesome 3.2.1

Comment: Other notes you may find useful: use fa-inverse on the i tag for the 1 to have it show up white instead of black, and use fa-2x (or fa-3x, etc) on the span tag to scale up.

Answer (score 23):

Here is what I use for counter overlays (badges) with FontAwesome (FA) 5.1. Unlike using the new `fa-layers` method, this does not require SVG+JS. Simply add a `data-count` attribute to `<i>` markup...

**CSS**

```
.fas[data-count]{
    position:relative;
}
.fas[data-count]:after{
    position: absolute;
    right: -0.75em;
    top: -.75em;
    content: attr(data-count);
    padding: .5em;
    border-radius: 10em;
    line-height: .9em;
    color: white;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,.75);
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 2em;
    font: bold .4em sans-serif;
}
```

**Markup**

```
<i class="fas fa-envelope" data-count="8"></i> &nbsp;
<i class="fas fa-address-book fa-lg" data-count="16"></i> &nbsp;
<i class="fas fa-bookmark fa-2x" data-count="4"></i> &nbsp;
<i class="fas fa-angry fa-3x" data-count="32"></i> &nbsp;
<i class="fas fa-bell fa-4x" data-count="2"></i>
```

**Example**

[image: FontAwesome 5.x Badge Counter Overlays]

**Conclusion**

Some FA icon sizes may require badge size/position tweaking, but works well for my purposes. All colors/positions can be adjusted for calendar overlays, text labels, or OP's star outline.

**Note**

Untested, but using the same CSS *should* work with older FA versions by changing `fas` class to `fa` instead.

Comment: very nice solution

Comment: the number is not appear

Comment: it did 4 years ago 

Comment: With my set up, I couldn't get the SVG version of Fontawesome 6 to work, so this was a great fall back!

Answer (score 9):

This can also be done using [Font Awesome Layers](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js#additional-styling) using version 5.0

```
<div class="fa-4x">
  <span class="fa-layers fa-fw" style="background:MistyRose">
    <i class="fas fa-circle" style="color:Tomato"></i>
    <i class="fa-inverse fas fa-times" data-fa-transform="shrink-6"></i>
  </span>

  <span class="fa-layers fa-fw" style="background:MistyRose">
    <i class="fas fa-bookmark"></i>
    <i class="fa-inverse fas fa-heart" data-fa-transform="shrink-10 up-2" style="color:Tomato"></i>
  </span>

  <span class="fa-layers fa-fw" style="background:MistyRose">
    <i class="fas fa-play" data-fa-transform="rotate--90 grow-2"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-sun fa-inverse" data-fa-transform="shrink-10 up-2"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-moon fa-inverse" data-fa-transform="shrink-11 down-4.2 left-4"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star fa-inverse" data-fa-transform="shrink-11 down-4.2 right-4"></i>
  </span>

  <span class="fa-layers fa-fw" style="background:MistyRose">
    <i class="fas fa-calendar"></i>
    <span class="fa-layers-text fa-inverse" data-fa-transform="shrink-8 down-3" style="font-weight:900">27</span>
  </span>

  <span class="fa-layers fa-fw" style="background:MistyRose">
    <i class="fas fa-certificate"></i>
    <span class="fa-layers-text fa-inverse" data-fa-transform="shrink-11.5 rotate--30" style="font-weight:900">NEW</span>
  </span>

  <span class="fa-layers fa-fw" style="background:MistyRose">
    <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
    <span class="fa-layers-counter" style="background:Tomato">1,419</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Requires SVG+JS method (eg: impossible when using the CSS-only CDN). See https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/layering