# How to increase font-awesome icon size which has text inside of it (using fa-stack)

Tags: css, responsive-design, font-awesome

I wanted to put text inside of a font-awesome icon (fa-circle). I came across this SO post: [How can I overlay a number on top of a FontAwesome glyph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737182/how-can-i-overlay-a-number-on-top-of-a-fontawesome-glyph)

The second answer (answer which has the most upvotes) uses this code:

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
    <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-stack-1x">1</i>
</span>
```

I want the text to be inside of a circle, so I changed "fa-star-o' to 'fa-circle", like so:

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-stack-1x">Sample text here.</i>
</span>
```

But the circle is a bit too small and the text does not fit inside of the circle so I tried making the circle bigger. In this link: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/ it says "You can even throw larger icon classes on the parent to get further control of sizing".

I'm not too sure how to do what is mentioned above. I tied

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x fa-lg"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-stack-1x">Sample text here.</i>
</span>
```

but it does not make the circle larger.

Any idea how I can make the font-awesome icon larger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an icon is part of a stack, you cannot change its size independently of the rest of the stack.

You can, however, change the overall size of the stack by adding one of the `fa-1x` `fa-2x` `fa-3x` etc classes to the parent as in the snippet below.

```html
<span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-stack-1x fa-inverse">1</i>
</span>
<span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
    <i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-stack-1x">1</i>
</span>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are ultimately trying to place text inside of a bordered circle, FontAwesome may be overkill. Instead you could use CSS, see the example below.

([Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/g0f5Lwo2/))

```css
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  position: relative
}
.circle span {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <span>Sample text here.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: oh okay. I was just trying to use font awesome because I wanted an official documented way of doing it which would be the most backwards compatible (rather than a css hack). I'll try the code you provided once I get back to work. Thanks.